# Javascript/Jquery - Run scripts after other script runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've ran into a problem with my webpage. I have a splash screen that is supposed to run when the page loads and it does that fine. I also have a loading screen that I want to run after splash screen, but I can't figure out how to make the splash screen run and then load the next line of code which would be the loading of the loading screen. How would I make the splash screen run and then the loading screen run? You can see the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
     $("#spinner").fadeOut( 3000 );
})
function SplashDone() { 
         document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none'; 
} 
function Init() { 
        document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'block'; 
        setTimeout(function(){ SplashDone(); }, 3000); 
}  
   window.onload = Init;
</script>
<body>
<div id="spinner">
<p>Loading</p>
</div>
<div id="splash">
<p>Splash</p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="SplashDone(); return false;">Skip</a></p>
</div>
```

So what I'm basically asking is how do I run as script after the page loads and then run another script after that script runs?

Comment: You realize you have a typo, `SplashDOne()`

Comment: Seems to be working just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/kdua5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to `showLoading` screen from the `splashDone` function. This way you make sure that loading screen will appear in both cases: if timeout runs out, and if user clicks `Skip` button:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    setTimeout(splashDone, 3000);
}

function splashDone() {
    document.getElementById('splash').style.display = 'none';
    showLoading();
}

function showLoading() {
    setTimeout(loadingDone, 3000);
}

function loadingDone() {
    document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
}
```

I also added `showLoading` function for this purpuse and some CSS to make splash and loading be visible by default so you don't have to show them initially on page load.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P8evf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming #splash refers to your splash screen and #spinner refers to your loading screen, the following will hide your splash screen 3 after page is loaded and then  fade out the loader within 3 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function(){
  $("#splash").css('display','none');
  $("#spinner").fadeOut( 3000 );
 }, 3000); 

});
```

**update:** JQ version of dfsq's [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/P8evf/2/)

*side note: i don't know why you are mixing JS and JQuery, IMHO it'll make more sence if you use either one of and increase readability..*

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(function(){ SplashDOne(); }, 3000);`

Should it be `SplashDone`?

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do though..

Comment: Yes I saw that typo but no that didn't fix what I'm going at.

Comment: I'm assuming that `spinner` is your loading screen; put the loading code at end of `SplashDone`? You can also make [callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Put your scripts in a separate .js file and then call it to execute after you have done your work by

```
$.getScript('url to js file');
```